# How to access current system audio sound to see actual sound volume?

Tags: c#, audio, volume

I need to get **actual** level of audio that is being played on windows 7 system, just like skype does it in settings:

[image: skype settings]

**I have found nothig about it, anyone here can help me out ?**

What i want to do is, i want to write a simply tool that will turn max volume up if the sound on windows is too quet or turn it down if sound is too loud.

Comment: I see what you mean. There might be a way to use NAudio (http://naudio.codeplex.com/) to begin recording from an output device and hence get the level that way. I will check it out later this evening and post and answer if I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this link:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/45693-controlling-sound-volume-in-c%23/

basically, you need to import this win32 api function:

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
public static extern int waveOutGetVolume(IntPtr hwo, out uint dwVolume);
```

then you can use it like that:

```
waveOutGetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, out CurrVol);
```

and you will get the volume level at 'CurrVol'

Comment: The question is not asking about the volume level (as set in the volume mixer). The question is asking about the signal level (post mixer) on an input channel. This will require sampling the signal and detecting the absolute signal peak (probably over a short time-window)

Answer (score 0):

Download the class NAudio and reference the DLL in your C# project.

Then add the following code to your project.
It will enumerate all audio devices get its volume level and tries to mute it.

```
        try
        {
            //Instantiate an Enumerator to find audio devices
            NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator MMDE = new NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator();
            //Get all the devices, no matter what condition or status
            NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceCollection DevCol = MMDE.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(NAudio.CoreAudioApi.DataFlow.All, NAudio.CoreAudioApi.DeviceState.All);
            //Loop through all devices
            foreach (NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDevice dev in DevCol)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Get its audio volume
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Volume of " + dev.FriendlyName + " is " + dev.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevel.ToString());

                    //Mute it
                    dev.AudioEndpointVolume.Mute = true;
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(dev.FriendlyName + " is muted");

                    //Get its audio volume
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(dev.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevel.ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Do something with exception when an audio endpoint could not be muted
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(dev.FriendlyName + " could not be muted");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //When something happend that prevent us to iterate through the devices
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Could not enumerate devices due to an excepion: " + ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Hi Mike, I copied your code but I encountered a problem. I couldn't get the `MMDeviceCollection` because it seems like the `MMDeviceEnumerator` is not initialized. The error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` always appear whenever I try to get the `MMDeviceCollection`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @AnnaFortuna Did you instantiate `NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator MMDE` with the new constructor?

Comment: I instantiated it this way: `NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator MMDE = new NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator();`